# Scene2D: How to use Image.setDrawable()

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to change the texture of an Image actor on my Scene2D stage, however I can't seem to get it working. It seems like setDrawable() doesn't really do anything.

For example, this will make the texture of the Image cookie.png:

```
Image itemImage = new Image(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cookie.png")))));
itemImage.setPosition(10, 10);
getStage().addActor(itemImage);
```

However, this will not:

```
Image itemImage = new Image();
itemImage.setPosition(10, 10);
itemImage.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cookie.png")))));
getStage().addActor(itemImage);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case it is not drawing because the constructor with no arguments doesn't set a width and height for the image, however the constructor that takes the drawable obtains the values from it.

To fix in your case:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cookie.png"));
Image itemImage = new Image();
itemImage.setPosition(10, 10);
itemImage.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(texture)));
itemImage.setSize(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
getStage().addActor(itemImage);
```

Also I'd save the textures as a field to later dispose of them (or you could obtain the drawable from the Image parse it to Texture and dispose it).